# Use of Heaviside operator versus Laplace transform in electrical engineering

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there a significant difference between Heaviside Operator p and Laplace transform operator s?

I'm wondering why Laplace transform is more commonly used to solve electrical circuits than using Heaviside operator?

Most books do not tell even about Heaviside but mostly Laplace transform. Is one method superior to the other one?

Comment: Whenever Oliver Heaviside used his "operator", after achieving a solution, he would show the solution exactly met what was required to be a solution of the guestion. Thus he did with confidence use the operator.

Answer (score 2):

The operator method introduced by Heaviside was empirical. It did work, but no formal proof was given.

The Laplace transform has a mathematical foundation and can even be used to show the correctness of the operator method.

The Heaviside method is not as general as the Laplace transform, for example it is not possible to have initial conditions.

So the Laplace transform is the more modern and more advanced method and is therefore preferred.

Comment: Laplace lived long before Heaviside but yet the application of Laplace transform is after Heaviside?

Comment: The application of the Laplace transform in *electrical engineering* is considerably more recent than the Laplace transform itself.  As Mario said, Heaviside didn't bother to prove his operator method and was somewhat controversial about it.  Thomas Bromwich was the one who eventually created a rigorous mathematical justification for Heaviside's method.

Comment: May as well add Jan Mikusinski's "The Operational Calculus," which takes a rigorous approach using the theory of con­volution quotients (Titchmarsh convolution theorem.)

Comment: This discussion reminds me of physicists using concepts of infinitesimals (a mathematically unproven idea) to solve problems (Leibniz) nearly two hundred years before Dedekind and Weierstrass finally used a (to my mind) a Rube Goldberg (but rigorous) approach to calculus based upon the limit theorem for derivatives. And subjected students to it ever since. It was Abraham Robinson, in 1961, who finally put rigor to infinitesimal values with his non-standard analysis. But it isn't taught, sadly. I always think in terms of infinitesimal variables and never using traditional derivatives methods.